# Mongodb pull all value inside an array within range condition

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a mongodb document like this :

```
arrayX : [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]
```

I want to delete all array elements between 30 and 35 so I want this as a result :

```
arrayX : [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37]
```

I have tried this :

```
db.collection("collectionX").updateOne({}, {

{ $pullAll : { arrayX : [$gte:30, $lte:35] } }

{ $pullAll : { arrayX : {$elemMatch:{ $gte:30, $lte:35 } } } }

{ $pull : { arrayX : {$in:[$gte:30, $lte:35] } } }

{ $pull : { arrayX : { $gte:30, $lte:35 } } } <======= WORKING

{ $pull : { arrayX : { $elemMatch: { $gte:30, $lte:35 } } } }
```

Comment: second from last try `{ $pull : { arrayX : { $gte:30, $lte:35 } } }` should work see the working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MmHkWlc1a0R)

Comment: Thank you ! I had another error when doing my test so I though it didn't work...